# Converting an NSString to a locale specific NSNumber

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsnumber

I am using the `KeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` and on some Phones you see an "," on the bottom left instead of an ".". It depends on the language settings of the phone! With the "." version everything works fine when i use [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[textField.text floatValue]] but with the "," version it says 2.0 for 2,5. Does anybody knows a work around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a local-aware string conversion which treats "2.5" and "2,5" correctly according to the default locale. Try:

```
NSNumber *num=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:textField.text];
```

From [NSDecimalNumber Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString%3a):

> Whether the NSDecimalSeparator is a
>   period (as is used, for example, in
>   the United States) or a comma (as is
>   used, for example, in France) depends
>   on the default locale.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! - [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:textField.text locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]] did help :)

Comment: An additional advice! If you want to change the the value of the textfield later, you should use [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:...] so it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[numberFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
NSNumber *num = [numberFormatter numberFromString:textField.text];
```

You can set the locale to us and always use the . annotation number.